# How to tell lombok that dont create getter and setter for a specific field

Tags: java, lombok

I have a Java Object like the following

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class SomeClass implements Comparable<SomeClass> {

    private int no;
    private Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> map1;
    private Map<String, LinkedHashSet<String>> map2;
}
```

Now I dont need a Getter / Setter for the field no, I want to set it in other ways. Now how to tell lombok that dont create Getter / Setter for the field no

Comment: I found this answer by copying the title of your question into Google. You can do the same and save yourself and others time.

Comment: Is the issue, that you don't want a `public` getter/setter or you absolutely must not have a getter/setter at all?

Comment: @Novaterata no getters/setters at all